# JavaScript scoping rules: how to use clearInterval() inside a callback

Tags: javascript

I am trying to learn JS using a course on PluralSight, and I found this example which prints "hello world" every second, and stops after 5 seconds. This is the intended solution, and it works.

```
let counter = 0;
const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
  console.log('Hello World');
  counter += 1;

  if (counter === 5) {
    console.log('Done');
    clearInterval(intervalId);
  }
}, 1000);
```

I am trying to get it to use a callback instead of an inline function, but I am not able to capture intervalID. I tried passing 'this' as function argument, but that also doesn't work. What is the correct way here?

```
// doesn't work
let counter = 0;
const f = (intervalID) => {
    console.log("Hello World");
    counter += 1
    console.log(intervalID)
    if (counter ==5){
        console.log("Done")
        clearInterval(intervalID)
    }

}

const intervalID = setInterval(f, 1000)
```

Comment: Remove the `intervalID` parameter. The first parameter to `setInterval` is `A function to be executed every delay milliseconds. The function is not passed any parameters, and no return value is expected.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `intervalID` is not an argument passed to `f`, but if you just remove the argument it will work because the `intervalID` is lexically scoped so that it's available inside `f`.

```
let counter = 0;
const f = () => {
    console.log("Hello World");
    counter += 1
    console.log(intervalID)
    if (counter ==5){
        console.log("Done")
        clearInterval(intervalID)
    }

}

const intervalID = setInterval(f, 1000)
```

OR passing in the `intervalID` is also fine:

```
let counter = 0;
const f = (intervalID) => {
    console.log("Hello World");
    counter += 1
    console.log(intervalID)
    if (counter ==5){
        console.log("Done")
        clearInterval(intervalID)
    }

}

const intervalID = setInterval(() => f(intervalID), 1000)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, the lexical scoping in JavaScript is really different. I don't even understand how is that possible! Can you explain a little bit more about it?